# Javascript SetInterval Function - Run Through X Arrays Then Back to Array [0] and Loop Again

Tags: javascript

I have 10 SVGs that needs to drawn/fill on load and updated every 10 minutes. Each SVG is about 500 boxes and 10 SVGs takes up 5000 steps. Furthermore, before the boxes are drawn/fill, a few calculations is needed.

I run them through **for** loops and it takes over 10 seconds to load, freezing the browser.

So, I thought of using SetInterval, firing only after the page is loaded and drawing/filling the SVG one at a time, after maybe 3 seconds have passed. Each of my SVGs is ID in this order, SVG1, SVG2, SVG3....etc.

So, I try to access getElement by their ID, 1,2,3...etc. I wrote a simple explanation of what my code does, but I can't seem to be able to progress through the SVG's ID.

```js
var z = 1;
let RunNonStop = setInterval(AddText, 2000, z);

function AddText(x) {
  document.getElementById("SVGdiv" + x.toString()).innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("SVGdiv" + x.toString()).innerHTML +
    "Add " +
    x.toString() +
    "<br>";
  if (z != 10) {
    z = z + 1;
  } else {
    z = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what's the problem exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Wonder if this is a job for Service Workers?

Comment: `x` is always the same value `1` that you passed to `setInterval`…

Comment: x is always 1. But what I want is, the first time it runs, x = 1, then second time, x =2. So that my code can access element, SVG1, SVG2 and so on....

Comment: I want it to run 10 times, then repeat back at SVG1.

Comment: Then omit `x` and use `z` instead.